# Except from performance, any other concern to store all things, except id, and fk, in string format?

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to know what is the idea behind the database value type. Except the use of space and performance, why the table field need to specific in whether int, float or other type. Is this any result for that?

Comment: Space and performance are not important enough? SQLite does something similar and I'm sure they have their reasons, but IMO this is just shoving all pegs into square holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain functions in MYSQL will act different depending on the data type. For example, if the MAX function is passed string values, it will return the maximum STRING value based on character, and if you were expecting it to sort values based on their numeric value, you'd be out of luck. Yes, MYSQL will sometimes cast things to numeric values when it needs to, but you can't count on it. This is because strings are fundamentally different from numeric values - and are treated differently.

Also, MYSQL has less data types than you think - a lot are simply aliases that dictate maximum storage and such. SQLite3 (used in iOS and other stuff) only has 5 data types - Null, Integer, Real, Text, and Blob.

Finally, you said ignoring performance, but performance *is* very important in MYSQL, especially with large data sets. When checking 100000 rows to get the largest value, why would you want to have to cast each one from a number to a string, if they ought to have been a number in the first place?

Comment: You would have to constantly use the MySQL CAST() or CONVERT() functions just to achieve what the database can do natively. i.e. CAST(`varchar_that_should_be_int` as INTEGER)

Answer (score 2):

By using the data types you allow the database to help you keep your data clean - if you should have an int in a quantity field it makes sure you don't accidentally stick a date in there.

Also it saves you from having to do strange conversions to do comparisons and such.  For example as a string how would you accurately compare dates?

Comment: Yes, I think that other than space and performance, data integrity is the biggest reason. You want some kind of barrier to garbage data, and data type is one basic way.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example as to why you would want to use a numeric attribute:

SELECT max(salary) FROM employees;
SELECT name from employee where salary > 2*avg_salary;

Comment: It's spelled "salary", by the way.

Comment: Thanks Buttle.  At least I was consistent :-)

Comment: You're welcome. P.S., if you click "edit" you can actually fix it! (if you want)

Comment: Done! Better late then never.